# How to deploy micro services on Heroku with multi module Maven project

Tags: heroku, spring-cloud, maven-assembly-plugin, heroku-toolbelt

I have a multimodule maven project which contains 4 micro services(github link [E2Open-POC](https://github.com/sunilsoni/e2open-poc)), To deploy this project I have created a new app , imported this project and deployed to Herok. But the problem is its not deploying all 4 projects.

Please suggest me how to deploy this multi module maven project on Heroku.

Comment: Did you find the solution ?, I have problem with this also

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploy multiple module java app on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865122/deploy-multiple-module-java-app-on-heroku)